# Empty migrate.sql with updateSQL against current database, but prints all data dictionary when ran against brand new database - SQL Server

Tags: liquibase

When I execute updateSQL against my existing database, I get empty migrate.sql. But when I execute against new database(brand new) it prints out the SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the changes you want to have on the existing database already there? If so, that is by design. The `updateSQL` command generates the SQL required to add any un-applied changesets in the changelog to the database. If there are no un-applied changesets, then there is no SQL to generate.

Comment: Thanks!! That explains it

Comment: You could convert that comment to an answer and get credit for answering your own question :-)